# jq filtering with certain key value

Tags: json, select, jq

I'm trying to get data with certain value. ex when device value is 10, get serialID qwer1234.
I have tried `jq-win64 -c ".devices[].serialID | select(.devices.device == 10)"` and I get error

`jq: error (at C:\test.json:60): Cannot index string with string "devices"`

I'm using jq1.6 on windows 10.

```
{
"devices": [
    {
        "device": 10,
        "serialID": "qwer1234",
    },
    {
        "device": 20,
        "serialID": "q1w2e3r4",
    },
    {
        "device": 30,
        "serialID": "wasd1234",
    }
]
```

Comment: Please fix the data so that it is valid JSON. You can easily check using `jq` (e.g. `jq length`) or a web site such as jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate jq query is:

```
.devices[] | select(.device == 10).serialID
```

However this assume the input is valid JSON.